# Flutter: Combine Multiple Future<T> Tasks

Tags: flutter, dart, future

How we can merge multiple FutureTask so that we can get a callback for all at the same response.

We use `Future<T>` like

```
Future<String> getData(int duration) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: duration)); //Mock delay
  return "This a test data for duration $duration";
}
```

Call above method like `getData(2).then((value) => print(value));`

If we want to call multiple Future Task, then how can we do that?

Comment: I believe you can already call the above method like that in dart, you just have to add `await` before `getData(2)`

Comment: check `Future.wait()`

Comment: @pskink: I have not used yet, will try to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For it, FutureGroup can be used to combine multiple streams

> FutureGroup provides us the functionality of combining multiple
> futures into one single group, which will give the callback at the end
> when all future tasks work gets completed.

**Dependency:**

```
dependencies:
  async: ^2.4.1
```

**How to implement FutureGroup?**

```
FutureGroup futureGroup = FutureGroup();
futureGroup.add(future1);
futureGroup.add(future2);
futureGroup.add(future3);
```

**Use:**

```
void main()  {
  Future<String> future1 = getData(2);
  Future<String> future2 = getData(4);
  Future<String> future3 = getData(6);
  FutureGroup futureGroup = FutureGroup();
  futureGroup.add(future1);
  futureGroup.add(future2);
  futureGroup.add(future3);
  futureGroup.close();
  futureGroup.future.then((value) => {print(value)});
}

Future<String> getData(int duration) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: duration)); //Mock delay
  return "This a test data";
}
```

**Output:**

> I/flutter ( 5866): [This a test data, This a test data, This a test
> data] // Called after 6 seconds.

**Note:** This will be called only once when all the Future Task gets completed, here it will run after 6 seconds.

Comment: The return types needs to be of the same type right?

Comment: @lolelo: Yes, it should be.

Answer (score 19):

To execute all futures concurrently, use `Future.wait`  This takes a list of futures and returns a future of lists:
Suppose you have these futures.

```
class CovidAPI {
  Future<int> getCases() => Future.value(1000);
  Future<int> getRecovered() => Future.value(100);
  Future<int> getDeaths() => Future.value(10);
}
```

You can get all the futures together using Future.wait([list of futures])

```
final api = CovidAPI();
final values = await Future.wait([
    api.getCases(),
    api.getRecovered(),
    api.getDeaths(),
]);
print(values); // [1000, 100, 10]
```

This is ideal when the futures are independent, and they don't need to execute sequentially.
Source : https://codewithandrea.com/videos/top-dart-tips-and-tricks-for-flutter-devs/